# Clojure test: Combining test-selectors with fixtures

Tags: clojure

Using Leiningen one can created test-selectors as follows:

```
  :test-selectors {:default (complement :slow)
               :slow :slow
               :all (constantly true)}
```

The problem is that if one of the tests that is marked as :slow is using [fixtures](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html#clojure.test/use-fixtures), the fixtures will be run even if the user specifies a different test suite.

What would be a good approach to address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What version of leiningen are you using? [This commit](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/commit/08eaf70781a72d84bc776f99a0592782a94e7b2a) (included in lein since version 2.3.0) changed the way that tests are skipped when using `:test-selectors`, and it is supposed to have fixed the exact issue you are describing.

You can check the version with `lein -v`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

My leiningen version is 2.5.1

The problem is that I have text fixtures that run `:once`, and if you check the corresponding issue to that commit, it is mentioned that the `:once` case is not covered: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1269

Comment: Ok, then assuming the `:once` fixture is producing some side effect, I guess your best bet is to make it idempotent, for example by checking the value of an atom, and then use it as an `:each` fixture. You might need to complement it with a `:once` fixture to undo the side effect, but only if it was produced (by checking the atom)

Comment: I guess using `:each` with an atom would work, although it feels fairly dirty :) I'll give it a try ...